# Would using the word "only" be correct in this context?

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

**Is it correct to use "`only`" here?**

> A: The movie was a bore. How did you even tolerate it ?!
>
> B: It was good only.

The "only" here is used to imply "`it wasn't that bad, it was tolerable`"

This when translated to Hindi, would make perfect sense. In fact there is where I guess this was derived from; Indians literally translating Hindi to English.

Answer (score 3):

"How was the movie? Was it great?"
"I wouldn't say it was great. It was only good." (But "merely" would be less awkward in this case).

Or:

"That move was so boring. How could you stand watching it?"
"I wouldn't say it was a total waste. It wasn't brilliant either."
"Are you serious?"
"Yeah. All in all, it was a pretty good effort. Nothing to rave about, but pretty good."
"You liked it, then."
"Sort of."
"You think it was great."
"No. I didn't say that. I think it was merely good."